# Add an identifier to a set of pages to access using a conditional tag

Tags: conditional-tags

For my website, i need to add a particular css file for a set of pages in wordpress which I am trying to do from functions.php.

For example:
This is a set of PAGES and not of type post. All these pages have title that starts with a particular string. Is there anyway I can detect the pages by a check using the string present in the title?

Or what else are the options available to do so?

**There are more than 10 pages so using is_page(id) is not a feasible solution.**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can't you check via `get_the_title()` and decide on that whether to enqueue or not?

Comment: If you have pretty permalinks enabled, the slug most likely also starts with this same string, so you could check whether the slug starts with that string just as easily as you could check whether the title starts with it.